# How to store filepath of file, drag-n-dropped into terminal in Python

Tags: python, input, terminal, drag-and-drop, tui

I have a TUI (textual user interface) application for which I'm trying to write an input manager that is able to discern whether a single keypress was provided or a file was drag-n-dropped into the application. I should then be able to save the key or the filepath into a variable. The user won't need to confirm her input with `ENTER`.

### Single keypresses

Reading single keypresses is easy using, for example, [readchar](https://pypi.org/project/readchar/) library.

### Drag-n-dropped files

For reading filepaths of drag-n-dropped files I use:

```python
import msvcrt

buf = ""

while True:
    c = msvcrt.getwch()

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        buf+=c
    elif buf:
        buf+=c
        print(buf)
        buf = ""
```

From `msvcrt`'s documentation I know that `msvcrt.getwch()` gets last keypress as a string and `msvcrt.kbhit()` returns `True` if a keypress is waiting to be read.

When run, this script will print filepaths of drag-n-dropped files and nothing else (prove me wrong).

However, I achieved this code mostly by trial and error. **It's messy, hard for me to explain and not OS-agnostic**. I couldn't find a library doing the same thing.

**Can someone simplify this code or guide me to a library that already handles my usecase?**

Comment: The code you pasted seems to be incomplete - it does not show how `drop` would ever have a value of `1`.

Comment: @dskrypa sorry, you're right I fixed it and also simpliefied it. However, my question persists - is there some easier, os-agnostic way to do this?